# Testing VoiceOver: how can I verify that my UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification notifications are working?

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

I'm developing an iOS app that I'd like to make fully accessible. Part of the app involves a sequence when playing cards are dealt, and then after user interaction, the hand ends and the next hand is dealt. When the hand has been dealt, I want to make impaired users aware.

So, after the hand is dealt (a sighted user sees the cards animate into place), I send a UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification notification like so:

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, nil);
```

When I verify in the Simulator using the Accessibility Inspector, everything looks fine: the notification is displayed. But, when I try to test using VoiceOver on a device, nothing seems to be happening. Is there something I'm missing here? How do I know that it works?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but I am a voiceover user. Have you considered using the UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning function to determine if voiceover is  running? If it is running you could play a sound when the new cards are delt and the user would know to reread the screen with voiceover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that my thinking of how Voiceover works was a bit off. It seems like the UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification isn't something to notify the user, it's to notify UIKit that voiceover elements have changed.

I wound up using a combination of sound effects and strategic use of the UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification notification to speak updates to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `nil` use a string. VoiceOver will use that string for speech.